# How to add an animation when using Ext.Viewport in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: animation, extjs, viewport

Here is my app.js:

```
Ext.application({
    views: ['SignIn'],

    launch: function() {
        // Initialize the signin view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.SignIn'));
    }
});
```

In `MyApp.view.SignIn`, I wanna set another view in the `Ext.Viewport`, so I just wrote `Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(someview)`.

It worked well. However, how could I add an animation when doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(someview)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem({xtype:'panelLogin'}, {type:'slide'});
```